# Mongodb loop with php through large-datasets

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, large-data

I want to iterate through all of my data >10mio records, but this timeouts.
My query looks like this:

```
    db.my_collection.find();
```

For processing the data i am using php, so i am doing an foreach of the cursor.
Any suggestions how to do this eventualy with limit and skip maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you use the mongo shell syntax if you query from the php client?

anyway I don't think you can hope to find and print 10mio of records in a resonable workload time without split your queries, also catch the Calimero suggestion and create your own pagination algorithm using skip limit.

> $cursor =
>   $db->collection->find($criteria, $projection)->sort($order)->skip($skip)->limit($limit);

give also a look at [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

or you could simply implement an external class that does it for you, check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php-libraries/) and find *MongoDB Pagination*

Comment: the approach i am using now is to use sort by id and limit to lets say 10k datasets. than i take the last id and start searching again with it

Answer (score 0):

You could use skip/limit, but also disable the timeout for this specific query :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php

Comment: setting the timeout isnt an option, because it takes way to long. Can you post an example of skip limit?